# Scheduling actions by date/time

Tags: thingsboard

Consider this scenario in ThingsBoard, default installation, single server:

There is only one device (for sake of simplicity) configured called "device_name", authenticated via token "device_token", no password. It already communicates successfully via MQTT with ThingsBoard and I already set up a small, working dashboard with a gauge and controls attached to the methods described below:

- *read_sensor*, returns value from internal sensor (let's say, for example, ambient light); Not directly relevant to the question, included to make the scenario clear.
- *activate*, turns on internal relay (controls lights, for example) and sets internal variable *status* to "on". Returns this variable.
- *deactivate*, turns off internal relay and sets internal variable *status* to "off". Returns this variable.
- *toggle*, turns internal relay on or off depending on previous value of the *status* variable based on "not" operation. Sets the *status*
  variable to the opposite of previous value and returns it.

The question is "how do I call the methods *activate* and *deactivate* at specific dates/times (server time) of the day using ThingsBoard rules and plugins?"

Examples:

- Call *activate* after 18:00 every weekday from monday to friday, but
  not on saturdays and sundays.
- Call *deactivate* after 08:00 every weekday from monday to friday,
  but not on weekends.

I already set up and configured the *Time*, *Telemetry* and *RPC* system plugins.

There is an alternate configuration of the device with an extra method *change(status)* that turns on or off the relay based on the *status* provided, sets the internal variable to the value provided and returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Thingsboard Professional Edition there is an action node "generator" that you can link to the PE feature "Scheduler". Within the scheduler it is possible to define an event being created according to a daily or weekly schedule.

For your application there would be two separate timers necessary for activation and deactivation. The events created must the be linked to a generator in your rule chain to trigger method execution.

Comment: Just to inform, this is a new functionality in the last release Thingsboard PE v2.1.

Comment: Sure, I've installed the Professional Edition (5-day "trial"), and successfully set up the Generator and the Scheduler.